# How to make javascript toggle button?

Tags: javascript

I have this code but it doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn_search">Search</button>
<input id="srh" type="search">
```

JS:

```
var btnSearch = document.getElementById("btn_search");
var search = document.getElementById("srh");

if (document.addEventListener) {
   btnSeach.addEventListener('click',activeSearch);
} else if (document.attackEvent) {
   btnSearch.attackEvent('onclick',activeSearch);
}

function activeSearch (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (search.style.width == '0') {
    search.style.width = '14.8em';
    search.style.opacity = '1';
} else if (search.style.width == '14.8em') {
    search.style.width = '0';
    search.style.opacity = '0';
}
```

I need a toggle button
What should I do?

Comment: You have a typo. The correct method name is [`attachEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent) (not *attack*).

Comment: Do you need to support IE8?

Comment: A toggle button is one that 'toggles' something on and off. The code you posted looks like code for a search input field. I am quite sure if you search the site you will find how to make a toggle button.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to 'toggle' on and off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might think about using a CSS class and **toggle()** to show/hide you element.

```js
var btnSearch = document.getElementById("btn_search");
btnSearch.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var search = document.getElementById("srh");
  search.classList.toggle("hidden");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#srh { width: 14.8em; }
#srh.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<button id="btn_search">Search</button>
<input id="srh" type="search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JQuery to simplify all the proccess. Make all the code as simple as:

```js
function magictoggle(a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    $("#btn1").attr("onclick", "magictoggle(0)");
    $("#searchbox").hide(1000);
    //1000 Are the miliseconds will take the box to hide
  } else {
    $("#btn1").attr("onclick", "magictoggle(1)");
    $("#searchbox").show(1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" onclick="magictoggle(1)">Search</button>
<input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="A search Box">
```