# I want to change the inner data of a button when clicked in html using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here on clicking the button the func() is being executed by javascript but I want the inner content to get changed when I click the button...

For example When I click the button the content "pause" should show "start" and again when I click "start" the content should show "pause"

I hope I am clear please someone help me. :)

```
<button class="button1" onclick="func()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: Where is the code of `func()`?

Comment: function func(){
  flag = 1;
                return;
}

Comment: I'm not sure you want to use CSS here. You could use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM to do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make javascript toggle button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376799/how-to-make-javascript-toggle-button)

Comment: Just target button1's class and then change the inner text..

Comment: Java script would do great can you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function func()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName('button1')[0].innerHTML = 'Your text here';
}
```

OR

Add the function's target as `this` in the HTML

```
<button class="button1" onclick="func(this)">Pause</button>

function func(target)
{
    target.innerHTML = 'Your text here';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much the second one worked awesome :) Thank you again :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use jquery :) like that below.
If you need to toggle a class just add this into the click() function (if the first state is pause):

```
$(this).toggleClass("start");
```

```js
$.fn.toggleHTML = function(a, b) {
    return this.html(function(_, html) {
        return $.trim(html) === a ? b : a;
    });
}


$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleHTML('Stop', 'Start');;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button1">Pause</button>
```