# How to make hover circular menu to toggle with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, web

I need to make this circular menu with toggle instead of hover 
i've tried https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show 
but still it's not working and my circle position is really bad.

and this menu is from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h9WH6YsMro&t=13s

My CSS :

```css
body{
    background-color: #f273ba;
    font-family: tahoma;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    margin: 190px auto;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f273ba;
    transition: 0.24s 0.2s;
}
.navbar .menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    left: -75px;
    border: 150px solid transparent;
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 1.4s 0.07s;
    z-index: -1;
}
.navbar .menu.active{
    transition: transform 0.4s 0.08s, z-index 0s 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar .menu li{
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
    transform-origin: 100px 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
}

.navbar:active .menu li{
    transition: all 0.7s;
}
.navbar .menu li a {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 59%;
    color: #f273ba;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(1){
    transition-delay: 0.02s;
    transform: rotate(85deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(1) a{
    transition-delay: 0.04s;
    transform: rotate(635deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(2){
    transition-delay: 0.04s;
    transform: rotate(125deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(2) a{
    transition-delay: 0.08s;
    transform: rotate(595deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(3){
    transition-delay: 0.06s;
    transform: rotate(165deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(3) a{
    transition-delay: 0.12s;
    transform: rotate(555deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(4){
    transition-delay: 0.08s;
    transform: rotate(205deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(4) a{
    transition-delay: 0.16s;
    transform: rotate(515deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(5){
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transform: rotate(245deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(5) a{
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transform: rotate(475deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(6){
    transition-delay: 0.12s;
    transform: rotate(285deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(6) a{
    transition-delay: 0.24s;
    transform: rotate(435deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(7){
    transition-delay: 0.14s;
    transform: rotate(325deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(7) a{
    transition-delay: 0.28s;
    transform: rotate(395deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(8){
    transition-delay: 0.16s;
    transform: rotate(365deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(8) a{
    transition-delay: 0.32s;
    transform: rotate(355deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(9){
    transition-delay: 0.18s;
    transform: rotate(405deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(9) a{
    transition-delay: 0.36s;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
a,a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Circular menu onclick</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">MENU
        <ul class="menu" onclick="click()">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/home?lang=en" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://rss.com/" class="fa fa-rss"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://id.pinterest.com/" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-web/" class="fa fa-skype"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="fa fa-github"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=id" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your JS?

Comment: You will need to add some Javascript which will define the function 'click()'.

Comment: here's what i have tried but this is messy i don't know how to fix it

Comment: <script>
        function clickMenu() {
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
        </script>

Comment: I used button on this one

Comment: Maybe this is of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376799/how-to-make-javascript-toggle-button

Answer (score 0):

use this for toggle onclick so you basically need to use toogle and querySelector instead and you need to change the :hover to .active
btw this is my first account for people who try to answered thank you <3

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMenu() {
       var navigation = document.querySelector(".navbar");
       var menuToggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
       var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
       navigation.classList.toggle("active");
       menuToggle.classList.toggle("active");
       menu.classList.toggle('active');
    }
    </script>
```